# Grafana drop down menu disappearing - unable to select fields

Tags: grafana

I'm having major issues when trying to manually create a new graph and select the data.  Not sure if it's some weird browser issue.

When selecting FROM or FIELD and the drop down appears with a range of values, i'm unable to scroll down through the options.  When i try and select the down menu to go through the choices the menu disappears.

If i know the field or option i can type it but trying to get to the bottom of a redis issue and need to go through the data we are getting and select the best options for an issue.

Seems to be anything where there's more options than in the space that can be displayed.  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

[image]
As soon as a click on the down button to scroll through the option it disappears

Any ideas or anyone come up against anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is to use the mouse scroll wheel.